# If Else Statements in Javascript for LiveCycle

Tags: javascript, if-statement, livecycle-designer

I am creating a form on Adobe LiveCycle that adds the numbers in different fields. I need to have the final field (Eligible Assets) add all the previous fields but exclude the sum of three of them and one in specific but only if it is greater than 60000. I've written the script as follows for the first part (to sum all the fields) this is in a field I've titled TotalAssets:

```
this.rawValue =Cash.rawValue+SavingsAccount.rawValue+ChildrensSavings.rawValue+CheckingAccount.rawValue+ValueHome1.rawValue+ValueHome2.rawValue+ValueVehicle1.rawValue+ValueVehicle2.rawValue+ValueVehicle3.rawValue+BusinessAccount.rawValue+BusinessAssets.rawValue+StocksBonds.rawValue+Retirement.rawValue+CDs.rawValue+OtherInvestments.rawValue+OtherAssets.rawValue;
```

This has worked fine, but the Retirement value if it is greater than 60000 should not be added into the calculation. This is what I've written (EligibleAssets):

```
if (Retirement.rawValue > 60000) {
Retirement.rawValue = 0; 
} else {
Retirement.rawValue == Retirement.rawValue ; 
}

this.rawValue = TotalAssets.rawValue - (ValueHome1.rawValue+ValueVehicle1.rawValue +Retirement.rawValue);
```

When I save the form as a PDF the first total of the fields calculates correctly but the second field comes up blank.

If you can spot what I'm missing or doing wrong I would really appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two simple problems that I see here.

First problem is that you are using `==` when you should be using `=`.

`==` - check if the left side *is equal* to the right side. Example: `if(x == 5) {`

`=` - *set* the left side *to* the value of the right side. Example: `x = 5`

In the first example we leave x alone, but in the second example we *change* x to 5.

So your code should look like:

```
} else {
    Retirement.rawValue = Retirement.rawValue;
}
```

However, when you think about this, this code doesn't actually do anything. `Retirement.rawValue` will not change.

This leads us to the second mistake in the code, at least, it looks to me like a mistake.

```
if(Retirement.rawValue > 60000) {
    Retirement.rawValue = 0;
}
```

This actually *changes* `Retirement.rawValue`, which might potentially change *what's inside the Retirement field of your form*. Worse, its possible that the form would *look* the same, but *act* differently when some *other* field calculates, since you've changed its `rawValue`. That would be a very tough bug to catch.

The solution is to create a new variable: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

So now we can create a new variable, set that variable to either the retirement amount or nothing, and then add that variable to the other `rawValue`s at the end:

```
var retirementOrZero;

if(Retirement.rawValue > 60000) {
    retirementOrZero = 0;
} else {
    retirementOrZero = Retirement.rawValue;
}

this.rawValue = TotalAssets.rawValue - (ValueHome1.rawValue + ValueVehicle1.rawValue + retirementOrZero);
```

Now we have a number that we can name anything we want, and we can change it however we want, without affecting any code but our own. So we start by checking if our retirement value is greater than 60000. If it is greater, we set our variable to 0. Otherwise, we set our variable to the retirement value. Then we add that variable we made, to the home and value cost.

As a final question, is it supposed to do

```
if(Retirement.rawValue > 60000) {
    retirementValueOrZero = 0;
}
```

or is it supposed to do

```
if(Retirement.rawValue > 60000) {
    retirementValueOrZero = 60000;
}
```

Of course, if you are setting it to 60000 instead of setting it to zero, you probably want to name your variable `cappedRetirementValue` or something like that -- just make sure you rename it everywhere its used!

Hopefully that helps!

Edit: You said you're only adding retirement value if it is greater than 60k, so what you want is this:

```
if(RetirementValue.rawValue > 60000) {
    retirementValueOrZero = RetirementValue.rawValue;
} else {
    retirementValueOrZero = 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood something on my end. I want anything less than 60000 in the retirement field excluded in the final calculation. Other than changing the greater than sign to a less than sign and possibly changing the variable name, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Only thing is to make sure you remember that changing a variable should look like `retirementValueOrZero = 0` and _not_ `retirementValueOrZero == 0`, and you should be good!

Comment: Perhaps a good mnemonic would be "a single = will change One side, a == will compare both of your Two sides"

Comment: One last follow up question, is it possible for the script to make it so if the retirement field is in fact greater than 60000, only the amount greater than 60000 will be considered in the final calculation. For example: if someone has 50000 in their retirement we would exclude the entire amount, (which is what I can finally do! :) ) but, if someone has 61000 in retirement, only the last 1000 will be considered in the final field.

Comment: if(RetirementValue.rawValue > 60000) {
    retirementValueOrZero = RetirementValue.rawValue - 60000;